# echo'd PHP encode JSON called via AJAX returns what exactly?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, object

I think I'm missing something here:

Using AjAX I get some data from a database and send it back in JSON format
    $jsondata = array();

```
while ($Row = mysql_fetch_array($params))
{

    $jsondata[]= array('cat_id'=>$Row["cat_id"], 
                          'category'=>$Row["category"], 
                     'category_desc'=>$Row["category_desc"],
                     'cat_bgd_col'=>$Row["cat_bgd_col"]);
};

echo("{\"Categories\": ".json_encode($jsondata)."};");
```

No problem so far I think.

On the cleint side I receive back the above into

```
ajaxRequest.responseText
```

and if I do this

```
var categoriesObject = ajaxRequest.responseText; 
alert(categoriesObject);
```

I see what I expect to see ie the entire array in the alert.

Where it all goes wrong is trying to access the response. The error I get is that the "categoriesObject" is not an object - if not what is it? what's bugginh me is that I can't even access it like this:

```
document.write(categoriesObject.Categories[0].category);
```

so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to parse the string into an object. Either using eval() which is problematic, or using a JSON parser. See here: http://www.json.org/js.html Side note, frameworks like jQuery have this built in

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. You should not create JSON manually. Use:

   ```
   echo json_encode(array('Categories' => $jsondata));
   ```

   or just

   ```
   echo json_encode($jsondata);
   ```

   I don't see a reason to add `Categories`.
2. You have to decode the JSON on the client side, using [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/json) (available in most browsers, but also available as [script](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js)):

   ```
   var data = JSON.parse(ajaxRequest.responseText);
   ```
3. If you want to be very correct, add

   ```
   header('Content-type: application/json');
   ```

   to your PHP script.

Comment: Very nice, covering all aspects. +1

Comment: The reason I used Categories is that ultimately I'm going to have several arrays in the data. also I did not provide the full php, but just for info you are very correct ! I was using header( "Content-type: text/javascript" ); not that it actually affects the data as far as I can see.

Answer (score 2):

Are you acutally parsing the JSON? It won't work without.

```
var categoriesObject = JSON.parse(ajaxRequest.responseText);
```

Comment: Thanks - same as the previous answer but I can't select both - sorry!