# How to put my JSON info into a jQuery Array

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have a project where I've created JSON data for Project Prices/Prices I've gotten this far and pretty much ran into a wall, any help at all would help! I've checked all over the web and on jQuery.getJSON but I wound up getting super confused.

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM xxx") 
 or die(mysql_error()); 

    $arr = array();
    $rs = mysql_query("SELECT product, price FROM products");
    while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($rs)) {
    $arr[] = $obj;
    }
    echo '{"products":'.json_encode($arr).'}';
```

I need to get the product price and product name into this jquery script

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
                /*** CONSTANTS ***/
                var KEY = 0;
                var VALUE = 1;
                /*** DEFINE DATA SETS ***/
                var POINTS = [ ["$productA", $PRICE ], ["$productB", $PRICE], ["$productC", $PRICE], ["$productD", $PRICE], ["$productE", $PRICE], ["$productF", $PRICE] ];
                var SHIPPING_COSTS = [ ["Pickup", 0], ["Next Day Delivery", 30], ["Same Day Print/Same Day Delivery", 65] ];

                for (var i = 0; i < POINTS.length; i++) {
                    $("#quantity").append("<option value='" + POINTS[i][VALUE] + "'>" + POINTS[i][KEY] + "</option>");
                }
                for (var i = 0; i < SHIPPING_COSTS.length; i++) {
                    $("#shipping").append("<option value='" + SHIPPING_COSTS[i][VALUE] + "'>" + SHIPPING_COSTS[i][KEY] + "</option>");
                }

                $("select.autoUpdatePrice, input.autoUpdatePrice").bind("mousedown click change", function(event) {
                    Calculate();
                });
                Calculate();    
            });


        function Calculate() {
            var net = parseFloat($("#quantity").val());
            /* Calculate the magical # by adding the form fields*/
            var designFee = $("#abcDesignFee").attr("checked") ? $("#abcDesignFee").val() : 0.0;
            var proofFee = $("#abcProofFee").attr("checked") ? $("#abcProofFee").val() : 0.0;
            var MyPrice;
            MyPrice = parseFloat( parseFloat(proofFee) + parseFloat(designFee) + net + parseFloat($("#shipping").val()));
            $("#DumpHere").html("Your Price: $" + formatNumber(MyPrice));
            $("#abcName").val($("#quantity").find(":selected").text() + " " + ProductNamePlural);
            $("#abcPrice").val(MyPrice);
        }
```

Comment: Don't put client/server code, or different languages, in the same code block.

Comment: mike, thanks -- I only posted them together to give an idea of how I was pulling my JSON array + how I needed to feed my jQuery Script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your PHP script, can you just `json_encode()` your array of objects without wrapping it in the string? And instead encode the JSON object like so:

```
<?php

// your script ...

echo json_encode($arr);
```

This creates an array of JSON encoded objects:

```
[{"name":"item 1","price":4.99},{"name":"item 2","price":9.99}]
```

Make an AJAX request in your JS to query your PHP script, and use jQuery's `$.each()` and `$.parseJSON()` methods to iterate over the returned JSON data:

```
$.post('get_products.php', { data: foo }, function(json) {
    $.each($.parseJSON(json), function(key, product) {
        console.log(product.name + ' ' + product.price);
    });
});
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: thanks for the tip, I think I'm getting on the right direction, thank you -- now to get the prices in the fields, lol.

Answer (score 1):

When I was learning - I had exactly the same problem - but it got answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846069/echod-php-encode-json-called-via-ajax-returns-what-exactly)

What I didn't realise at the time was that you can use ***object notation*** (which is the ON of json) to access the data you sent.

If you look at my question and the answer I selected, once you have sent the data back to javascriot you can access it easily. In my example it would be as straitforward as using `data.catagory_desc` in javascript to find the data that was encoded.